# If $z'\le az+b$ then $z(t)\le z_0+bt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, exponential-function

> If $z$ satisfies; $z'\le az+b$, $\ z(0)=z_0>0$ with constants $a,b$ why is true that $z(t)\le z_0+bt$, if $a=0$

It is clear that it can't be justified only by integrating. We had only Gronwall lemma in the lecture, the other case, where $a\neq 0$ I have already proved (To show was: $z(t)\le z_0e^{at}+\frac ba(e^{at}-1)$), but didn't use the lemma, now I'm stuck, do you have an idea, Thanks.

Comment: If $a=0$, then $z'\leqslant b$ hence...

Comment: Why can't you just integrate both sides after setting $a=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have $a=0$ then $z'\leq b$. So you just have to integrate the inequality

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{t}z'dt \leq \int_{0}^{t}bdt,
\end{equation}

and obtain

\begin{equation}
z(t)\leq z_0 +bt.
\end{equation}

Comment: OK, ok, I did something wrong. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If
$$
z'\le az+b,\quad\text{then}\quad \mathrm{e}^{-at}\big(z'(t)-az(t)\big)\le b\,\mathrm{e}^{-at},
$$
or
$$
\big(\mathrm{e}^{-at}z(t)\big)'\le -\frac{b}{a}\big(\mathrm{e}^{-at}\big)'
$$
and integrating in $[0,t]$ we obtain
$$
\left(\mathrm{e}^{-at}z(t)+\frac{b}{a}\mathrm{e}^{-at}\right)-
\left(z(0)+\frac{b}{a}\right)\le 0,
$$
or
$$
z(t)\le \left(z(0)+\frac{b}{a}\right)\mathrm{e}^{at}-\frac{b}{a}.
$$
If $a=0$, then see Pedro's answer.

Comment: I did exactly the same, so both cases don't require the lemma.

Comment: The working in this is actually completely fine in both cases for $a$ up until the evaluation of the integral, the only difference between the two cases is that the antiderivative of $e^{at}$ being $1/a e^{at}$ for non zero $a$, but $t$ for when $a=0$.

Comment: @Matt Rigby Yes, no need for case analysis, thanks a lot.